# why am i getting error when i m using short circuit to set default value for form input in react?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, jsx, logical-operators, short-circuiting

i'm creating form component to use the form in 2 different page and i want to check if is value is defind set it or give it a empty string ,but it doesn't work whem short circuit being used or ternary operator

here is my code :

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import classes from "./EventForm.module.css";

function EventForm({ method, event }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  function cancelHandler() {
    navigate("..");
  }

  return (
    <form className={classes.form}>
      <p>
        <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
        <input
          id="title"
          type="text"
          name="title"
          required
          defaultValue={event.title || ""} // this line 
        />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label htmlFor="image">Image</label>
        <input
          id="image"
          type="url"
          name="image"
          required
          defaultValue={event.image || ""}
        />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label htmlFor="date">Date</label>
        <input
          id="date"
          type="date"
          name="date"
          required
          defaultValue={event.date || ""}
        />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
        <textarea
          id="description"
          name="description"
          rows="5"
          required
          defaultValue={event.description || ""}
        />
      </p>
      <div className={classes.actions}>
        <button type="button" onClick={cancelHandler}>
          Cancel
        </button>
        <button>Save</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default EventForm;
```

and i'm getting this error : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title') while it should be fixed

i tried ternary operator and short circuiting but it only lead to failiure

Answer (score 0):

It was thrown error because your `event` might is `null` or `undefined`

The error said: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')`
-> **It means `undefined.title` crash here**

There are many ways to fix it.

- Do check for `event` before calling
- Set default value `event = {}`
- Or using Optional chaining (?.) `event?.title` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining